# Can I use somehow printpoints in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

There is a nice hack in eclipse, that I can use "[printpoints](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19825.html)" during debugging:

[image]

This is especially useful if I have a threading issue, and I would change the behaviour of my program with a breakpoint, which stops the execution.

I tried the same in IntelliJ, and it does not work. Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the red breakpoint circle by the line number, click on 'more' at the bottom of the popup, you can then either log a fixed message to the console when that line is hit, or log an evaluated expression